# How to create a new Linked List revolving around a user input?

Tags: java, string, input, linked-list

I want to create a new Linked List revolving around a user inputted name. For example if a user inputs "eBay", I want to create a new list with that name.

I am new to Java and I am not 100% sure about all of the function calls that I can use.

I was able to create a set name for a linked list and was able to use it. But I am not sure how to use an inputted name to create a new list.

This is the current code I have. But It is not what I am wanting to do.

```
 public Controller() {
        LinkedList<Stock> googList = new LinkedList<Stock>();
        LinkedList<Stock> amazList = new LinkedList<Stock>();
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter the company name or 3 to quit: ");
            String stockSelect = input.next();
            if(stockSelect.compareTo("3") == 0)
                break;
            System.out.print("Input 1 to buy, 2 to sell: ");
            int controlNum = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("How many stocks: ");
            int quantity = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("At what price: ");
            double price = input.nextDouble();

            if(controlNum == 1) {
                if(stockSelect == 1) {
                    Controller.buyStock(googList, "Google", quantity, price);
                }
                else
                    Controller.buyStock(amazList, "Amazon", quantity, price);
            }
}
```

Is there any way to use "input.next();" to retrieve what the user inputted and create a new list. Something along the lines of:

```
LinkedList "<"Stock> list1 = new LinkedList "<"Stock> (input.next());
```

Also, is there any way I can create separate lists in order to buy stock for each separate company name that a user inputs?

Comment: you can use ```List<Stock> list;
    if (input.next() == "eBay") {
        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Stock("")));
    }```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add an item to your list you can use

```
googList.add(stockSelect);
```

see documentation
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

to read the elements of the list you can use an the get(int index) method
or an iterator

```
Iterator iterator = googList.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
   System.out.println(iterator.next());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is a `HashMap`.

```
HashMap<String, LinkedList<Stock>> stockLists = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<Stock>>();
```

Instead of `controlNum`, you will use a `controlName`.

And then instead of `if (controlNum == 1)` and the following lines, you will write:

```
if (!stockLists.containsKey(controlName)) {
    stockLists.put(controlName, new LinkedList<Stock>());
}

LinkedList<Stock> currentList = stockLists.get(controlName);
Controller.buyStock(currentList, controlName, quantity, price);
```

Basically, the if will check if you already have a list with that name and create one if not. After that you just get the list with that name and call the buyStock method for it.

---

Lists do not have names. You were talking about the variable names and that's something you probably shouldn't (and can't) change at runtime.

The alternative to this is a HashMap, which is basically a collection of key-value pairs. You can create values for any keys and get the correct values.

For example:

```
HashMap<String, String> exampleMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

This will map Strings to Strings. What could you use it for? Well, for example you could use last names as keys and first names as values.

```
exampleMap.put("Albertson", "Albert");
exampleMap.put("Smith", "John");
exampleMap.put("Cooper", "Hank");
```

Now if the user would enter his last name, you could use the HashMap to look up his first name.

```
// Let's assume his last name is in the variable lastName
System.out.println("Hello, " + exampleMap.get(lastName) + "! Nice to see you again!");
```

Of course, your example is a bit trickier as you don't want to just get a first name but an entire list but that only looks a bit scarier and is actually no big deal at all. Instead of the second String type you simply use your List type as seen above.

The only real difference here is that since you do need a list for your method to work and it is possible that the user inputs something that doesn't have one yet, you need to check that first and create a list for the given key if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking. If you are asking if it's possible create a new `List` that is named in your code based on user input that wouldn't make sense because you wouldn't have a way of referencing that list.

**Instead I would use:**

```
Map<String, List<Stock>> myLists = new Hashmap();
```

This way you can have an associated name with each list you generate.

**Add a new list with:**

```
myLists.put("eBay", new LinkedList<>());
```